# Show double format C#

Tags: c#

I have random number:

```
Random log = new Random();
```

I use it on Timer:

```
timer1.Interval = log.Next(200000, 570000);
```

This part converting mili seconds in a minutes:

```
double timme = timer1.Interval / 1000 / 60;
```

So `timme` is always whole number, I want double.
How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are experiencing integer division.

```
double timme = timer1.Interval / 1000.0 / 60.0;
```

(Strictly speaking only one of the two constants need to be floating point value)

Answer (score 0):

Alternativelly, you can use suffixes:

```
double timme = timer1.Interval / 1000D / 60D;
```

The character "D" after a number indicates that the fixed number will be a double.

You can do this for decimals too, if needed:

```
decimal timme = timer1.Interval / 1000M / 60M;
```

More informating: [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/suffix)